# How can I match an ImageView height to its parent that is wrap_content? (RecyclerView Item)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have a `RecyclerView` item with a `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout`'s height is set to `wrap_content`. Inside that `LinearLayout`, I would like to have an `ImageView` with a triangle shape that matches the height of the `LinearLayout` to get something like this:

[image]

With a fixed height for `LinearLayout`, I can just set it in XML:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

To get the same result with a variable height, I've tried to set the `ImageView` height and width to 0 and then adjust them programmaticaly inside `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.mLinearLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int layoutHeight = holder.mLinearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

holder.mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = layoutHeight;
holder.mImageView.getLayoutParams().width = layoutHeight;

holder.mImageView.requestLayout();
```

It looks like the resizing of the `ImageView` works but it doesn't show the image. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I accidentally removed the image source from my XML. The above code shows an image now but it still does not work properly.

To get the right height, you have to replace the measure arguments:

```
holder.mLinearLayout.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        );
```

I'm not sure if that's the best solution but it works.